# Mapstruct not generating mapper class in springboot

Tags: java, maven, mapstruct

I'm trying to put together a project that uses mapstruck, but I'm having some trouble s that the class implementing the SourceToTargetMapper interface is not being generated.

Mapper:

```
@Mapper
public interface CreatePersonMapper {
    CreatePersonMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(CreatePersonMapper.class);
    DTOIntPerson personToDTOIntPerson(Person person);
}
```

When I build the programm there's no error, but the classes aren't being generated.

I believe there's some problem with my pom, probably there’s something missing or misplaced in the build/plugin :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.sac.arq.servicing.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>pom-padre-frontend</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.4.4</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sac.ergo.riskbusinessadmissions</groupId>
    <artifactId>risk-business-admissions</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>risk-business-admissions</name>
    <repositories />
    <pluginRepositories />
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <podam.version>7.2.3.RELEASE</podam.version>
        <mockito-all.version>1.9.5</mockito-all.version>
        <mockito-core.version>1.9.5</mockito-core.version>
        <enax_bdd_test_core.version>1.1.7</enax_bdd_test_core.version>
        <enax_bdd_test_impl.version>1.1.5</enax_bdd_test_impl.version>
        <jackson-core.version>2.9.8</jackson-core.version>
        <jackson-annotations.version>2.9.8</jackson-annotations.version>
        <jacoco.version>0.8.3</jacoco.version>
        <eiaq_routines.version>1.0.6</eiaq_routines.version>
        <enax_validation.version>1.0.4</enax_validation.version>
        <conditions.version>1.0.2</conditions.version>
        <kygg_imcUtils.version>1.0.0</kygg_imcUtils.version>
        <openpojo.version>0.7.3</openpojo.version>
        <guava.version>27.1-jre</guava.version>
        <roo.version>2.0.0.RELEASE</roo.version>
        <!-- <arq-spring-core-spi.version>5.4.0.0</arq-spring-core-spi.version> -->
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Core ASO -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sac.jee.arq.spring.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>arq-spring-servicing-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sac.jee.arq.spring.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>arq-spring-connector-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sac.jee.arq.spring.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>arq-spring-restutils</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sac.jee.arq.spring.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>arq-spring-core-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sac.jee.arq.spring.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>arq-spring-backend-apx</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sac.jee.arq.spring.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>arq-spring-backend-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sac.jee.arq.spring.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>arq-spring-backend-otma</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sac.jee.arq.spring.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>arq-spring-backend-ps</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--ThirdParty ASO -->
        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!-- <groupId>com.sac.jee.arq.spring.core</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>arq-spring-core-spi</artifactId> -->
        <!-- <version>${arq-spring-core-spi.version}</version> -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sac.jee.arq.spring.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>arq-spring-servicing-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Infraestructure Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sac.infrastructure.multichannel.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>multi-channel-infrastructure-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sac.infrastructure.multichannel.serv</groupId>
            <artifactId>multi-channel-infrastructure-serv-facade</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ROO dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.roo</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.roo.annotations</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ThirdParty dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.openpojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>openpojo</artifactId>
            <version>${openpojo.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-codec.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Dependencias Swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger-jaxrs.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>uk.co.jemos.podam</groupId>
            <artifactId>podam</artifactId>
            <version>${podam.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito-all.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Cucumber dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sac.enax.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>enax_bdd_test_core</artifactId>
            <version>${enax_bdd_test_core.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sac.enax.global.bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>enax_bdd_test_impl</artifactId>
            <version>${enax_bdd_test_impl.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-core.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-annotations.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${httpclient.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>${httpcore.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Rutines and Libraries dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sac.eiaq</groupId>
            <artifactId>eiaq_routines</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sac.jee.arq.spring.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arq-spring-connector-host-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sac.jee.arq.spring.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arq-spring-connector-host-apx</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <version>${eiaq_routines.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sac.enax</groupId>
            <artifactId>enax_validation</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sac.jee.arq.spring.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arq-spring-connector-host-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sac.jee.arq.spring.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arq-spring-connector-host-apx</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <version>${enax_validation.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sac.enax</groupId>
            <artifactId>conditions</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sac.jee.arq.spring.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arq-spring-connector-host-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sac.jee.arq.spring.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arq-spring-connector-host-apx</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <version>${conditions.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sac.kygg</groupId>
            <artifactId>kygg_imcUtils</artifactId>
            <version>${kygg_imcUtils.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>ergo_${project.artifactId}</finalName>

        <!-- Core -->
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${arq.spring.jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${arq.spring.jdk.version}</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <!-- other annotation processors -->
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-proc:only</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-resources-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>generacionFacade.xml</descriptor>
                        <descriptor>generacionSN.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                    <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-deploy-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${aspectj-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <complianceLevel>${arq.spring.jdk.version}</complianceLevel>
                    <outxml>true</outxml>
                    <aspectLibraries>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>com.sac.jee.arq.spring.core</groupId>
                            <artifactId>arq-spring-servicing-core</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>com.sac.jee.arq.spring.core</groupId>
                            <artifactId>arq-spring-restutils</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                    </aspectLibraries>
                    <source>${arq.spring.jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${arq.spring.jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Test -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>${surefireArgLine} -XX:-UseSplitVerifier</argLine>
                    <printSummary>false</printSummary>
                    <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*_Roo_*</exclude>
                        <exclude>${skip.tests}</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>com/sac/enax/cards/dao/model/**/*.class</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</destFile>
                            <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-unit-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- IDE -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-eclipse-plugin.version}</version>
                <!-- Note 2.8 does not work with AspectJ aspect path -->
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.eclipse.ajdt.core.ajbuilder</name>
                            <arguments>
                                <aspectPath>org.springframework.aspects</aspectPath>
                            </arguments>
                        </buildCommand>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</name>
                        </buildCommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.eclipse.ajdt.ui.ajnature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>com.springsource.sts.roo.core.nature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-idea-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-idea-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <dependenciesAsLibraries>true</dependenciesAsLibraries>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Servers -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tomcat-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webAppConfig>
                        <contextPath>/${project.name}</contextPath>
                    </webAppConfig>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>unit-test</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <build.profile.id>unit-test</build.profile.id>
                <skip.tests>**/RunIntegradoTest.java</skip.tests>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <properties>
                <build.profile.id>integration-test</build.profile.id>
                <skip.tests>**/business/**, **/dao/**, **/facade/**,
                    **/TestGetterSetter.java</skip.tests>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the spring componentModel in mapper class @Mapper(componentModel = "spring") and try adding this dependency

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
     <version>3.3.2</version>
     <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

When using Maven and the `annotationProcessorPaths` you need to make sure that the version of the maven-compiler-plugin is at least 3.5.1 or newer. If you are using the Spring Boot as a parent in your parent then it should work, otherwise it is not OK.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the spring componentModel in mapper class `@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")` and the expected dependency configuration of annotation processors which is described on the mapstruct site [dependency config](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#_apache_maven)